# Script breaks when bundled with webpack, _typeof called before it's defined

Tags: javascript, webpack, typeof, referenceerror

I have a script that runs independently, but when I incorporate it into the project I'm working on this error is thrown.

[_typeof Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lsqk2.jpg)

There is a method on an object that parses JSON.  When using `typeof variable === 'object'` in the method this error throws, but when I switch to `variable instanceof Object` it runs successfully.

Also, it only throws for `typeof variable === 'object'`, if I switch to a primitive like `typeof variable === 'string'`, the error doesn't throw.

When I build with an inline-source-map it looks like _typeof is called before it is defined.

I'm using webpack 4.1.1 and webpack-cli 2.0.12

Comment: Strange.  Did you read through this link http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#types.typeof.  Are you using the babel loader or optimizations?  Perhaps, you can use a separate loader for script and run it through different transformation, try no babel, and no optimizations.